# box selection went wrong

Tags: interface, selection-tools

[image]

and I dont know how to get back. Actually I intended to cut the sphere into half by box selecting one half. Accidentely I pressed CMD B instead of just B. Redo not possible, the rest of the model is not visible anymore.

Comment: Hello :). *Cmd + B* sets render region. Use *Cmd + Alt + B* to clear it.

Comment: doesnt work, the box selection appears but nothing changes

Comment: Hey :). If the linked answer doesn't help, you'll need to provide more details.